# Adding a local package inside an npm package for react native. Gives not found error

Tags: ios, react-native, npm

I'm trying to create a react-native npm package. I added a local package (x) in the iOS project of that npm package. When I pack this package into an npm package and include it into a project. it gives me error that package (x) not found.